# Get Parent Class from external .cs file

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a small Console app where I search for keywords in a large group of `.cs` files. I now want to follow the inheritance of a subfile to its parent root file. So far I have completed this by using a very noobish method that I don't like.

I think Reflection will be perfect but then I struggle to figure out how to use Reflection on an external file.

Can someone advise me on how I can achieve this?

**EDIT:**

```
static string GetParent(string location, string word)
{
    string[] file = location.Split(new[] { "\\" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

    try
    {
        using (StreamReader test = new StreamReader(location))
        {
            while ((line = test.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (word == "ControlEventStates" && line.Contains(file.Last().ToString().Replace(".cs", "")))
                {
                    string[] a = line.Split(new[] { " ", "(", ")", ";", ".", ",", "<", ">" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                    for (int p = 0; p < a.Length; p++)
                    {
                        if (a[p] == ":" && a[p + 1] != "FunctionBase")
                        {
                            recValue = a[p + 1] + ".cs";

                            foreach (var item in Frontendfiles)
                            {
                                //newlocation = item;
                                string loc = Path.GetFileName(item);
                                if (loc == recValue)
                                {
                                    GetParent(item, word);
                                }
                                else if (loc != recValue)
                                {
                                    FindLine(item, a[p + 1] + " : ");                                             
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (location != "" && location != null)
                    {
                        //LinesList = FindLine(newlocation, word);
                        return line;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

So as I said this is terrible coding for what I want to accomplish. Basically I search for the line containing the current class name then filtering out the strings to find where the parent file is. Then I use the parent file name to search for its directory and then start the process over again.

Comment: Reflection is on assemblies, if you need to read code then perhaps you could use Roslyn?

Comment: Can you show us your noobish method?

Comment: I will check out Roslyn have not used it before @LasseV.Karlsen

Comment: Edit made @mjwills be kind. =|

Comment: @hasan Stack Snippets should only be used for HTML, CSS, and/or JavaScript, not C#.